# How to create multi color top border with background on a div?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is it possible to create a two dimensional gradient like the following image?

[image: What I need]

Currently, I can achieve only one of the following two i.e to right Or bottom

```
background: rgba(247,149,29,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(247,149,29,1) 0%, rgba(247,149,29,1) 16%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 17%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 33%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 34%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 56%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 56%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 57%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 73%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 73%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(247,149,29,1)), color-stop(16%, rgba(247,149,29,1)), color-stop(17%, rgba(237,28,35,1)), color-stop(33%, rgba(237,28,35,1)), color-stop(34%, rgba(43,56,144,1)), color-stop(56%, rgba(43,56,144,1)), color-stop(56%, rgba(27,118,188,1)), color-stop(57%, rgba(27,118,188,1)), color-stop(73%, rgba(27,118,188,1)), color-stop(73%, rgba(0,167,156,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,167,156,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(247,149,29,1) 0%, rgba(247,149,29,1) 16%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 17%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 33%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 34%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 56%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 56%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 57%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 73%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 73%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(247,149,29,1) 0%, rgba(247,149,29,1) 16%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 17%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 33%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 34%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 56%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 56%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 57%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 73%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 73%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(247,149,29,1) 0%, rgba(247,149,29,1) 16%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 17%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 33%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 34%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 56%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 56%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 57%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 73%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 73%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(247,149,29,1) 0%, rgba(247,149,29,1) 20%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 20%, rgba(237,28,35,1) 40%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 40%, rgba(43,56,144,1) 60%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 60%, rgba(27,118,188,1) 80%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 80%, rgba(0,167,156,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7951d', endColorstr='#00a79c', GradientType=1 );
```

1. [image]
2. [image]

I want to get a right bottom gradient with mutli color on top and black on bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of possible variants:

**1- Using Multiple Backgrounds:**

We can draw this shape by applying multiple background images on a `div` element and by precisely controlling their size.

Consider the following styles:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f7941d 20%, #ed1c24 20%,
                                            #ed1c24 40%, #2b3990 40%,
                                            #2b3990 60%, #1b75bc 60%,
                                            #1b75bc 80%, #00a79d 80%),
                  linear-gradient(#333, #333);

background-size: 100% 8px, 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

We are using CSS3 [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) to create 2 different background images and we have used `background-size` property to limit the size of first image.

***Note:*** The order of images in `background-image` property is important. Change in the order wouldn't produce the desired output.

*Output Image:*

[image: Output Image]

*Working Demo:*

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f7941d 20%, #ed1c24 20%, #ed1c24 40%, #2b3990 40%, #2b3990 60%, #1b75bc 60%, #1b75bc 80%, #00a79d 80%),
                    linear-gradient(#333, #333);
  background-size: 100% 8px, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

**2- Using Pseudo Elements:**

We can draw top border using a pseudo element.

- Create a layer with `::before` or `::after` pseudo element and place it on above the parent element with `position: absolute`.
- Create the desired background using CSS3 `linear-gradient` and apply this on the layer create above.

*Working Demo:*

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 60px;
}

.box::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f7941d 20%, #ed1c24 20%, #ed1c24 40%, #2b3990 40%, #2b3990 60%, #1b75bc 60%, #1b75bc 80%, #00a79d 80%) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:after` element to get something like the image you provided:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.gradient {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  background: rgba(247, 149, 29, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 16%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 17%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 33%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 34%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 57%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    left top,
    right top,
    color-stop(0%, rgba(247, 149, 29, 1)),
    color-stop(16%, rgba(247, 149, 29, 1)),
    color-stop(17%, rgba(237, 28, 35, 1)),
    color-stop(33%, rgba(237, 28, 35, 1)),
    color-stop(34%, rgba(43, 56, 144, 1)),
    color-stop(56%, rgba(43, 56, 144, 1)),
    color-stop(56%, rgba(27, 118, 188, 1)),
    color-stop(57%, rgba(27, 118, 188, 1)),
    color-stop(73%, rgba(27, 118, 188, 1)),
    color-stop(73%, rgba(0, 167, 156, 1)),
    color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 167, 156, 1))
  );
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 16%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 17%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 33%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 34%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 57%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 16%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 17%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 33%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 34%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 57%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 16%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 17%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 33%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 34%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 57%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 20%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 20%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 40%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 40%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 60%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 60%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 80%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 80%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
}

.gradient:after {
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
</div>
```

EDIT: Since you want to show some text, it's better to use inner `div` instead of `:after` pseudo-element:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.gradient {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  background: rgba(247, 149, 29, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 16%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 17%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 33%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 34%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 57%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    left top,
    right top,
    color-stop(0%, rgba(247, 149, 29, 1)),
    color-stop(16%, rgba(247, 149, 29, 1)),
    color-stop(17%, rgba(237, 28, 35, 1)),
    color-stop(33%, rgba(237, 28, 35, 1)),
    color-stop(34%, rgba(43, 56, 144, 1)),
    color-stop(56%, rgba(43, 56, 144, 1)),
    color-stop(56%, rgba(27, 118, 188, 1)),
    color-stop(57%, rgba(27, 118, 188, 1)),
    color-stop(73%, rgba(27, 118, 188, 1)),
    color-stop(73%, rgba(0, 167, 156, 1)),
    color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 167, 156, 1))
  );
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 16%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 17%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 33%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 34%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 57%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 16%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 17%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 33%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 34%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 57%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 16%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 17%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 33%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 34%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 56%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 57%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 73%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 0%,
    rgba(247, 149, 29, 1) 20%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 20%,
    rgba(237, 28, 35, 1) 40%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 40%,
    rgba(43, 56, 144, 1) 60%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 60%,
    rgba(27, 118, 188, 1) 80%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 80%,
    rgba(0, 167, 156, 1) 100%
  );
}

.text {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @fen1x . But it hides the inner <div> contents. There is text in div's body which will be displayed on that black area. Sorry didn't mention that before

Comment: @Abdul You didn't mention it in your question. Can you edit it to show the desired result?

Comment: <div class="gradient">
         SECURITY CODE VERIFICATION
      </div>  UPDATED the question

Comment: Thank you for quick response @fen1x